# Long networking operation with Volley library and Service

Tags: android, service, intentservice, android-volley

I have a long networking task to do once the user logs in correctly. This task consists in the following:

1) 4 calls to a REST web service.

2) Data obtained in point 1 is populated into a sqlite database.

3) Download several images from the same REST web service (for example 400).

I'm using Volley as my default networking library to do that stuff.

My question is:

Do you have some advice that I should take in consideration? Is IntentService the best approach to achieve that kind of tasks or Service is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Volley running as a Service is a good approach.

Incorporate a message bus, like Otto, to transfer data to your app. The service can publish events to the bus when its operation finishes, and your app should register to the event and perform an action on completion.

The bus allows you achieve async behaviour and a clean design.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer by @avendael kinda misses the question, i guess.

`IntentService` extends `Service` and has one major limitation - it executes the tasks sequentially and not in parallel. But Volley, for networking esp, you can have multiple connections to server. The default value is 4 but it's configurable.

Another major limitation with `IntentService`, though that's one relevant for the question posted here, is that it's very well suited for `started` type of services and not for `binding` to it. And `Volley` i believe is similar to `IntentService` in that regard.

Hope that helps.